# Elasticsearch (2.4) must_not filter and arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering

I've the following array structure in my documents:

```
"usages": [
    {
     "type": 1,
     "area": 207
    },
    {
     "type": 6,
     "area": 629
    },
    ...
]
```

How to write a query where the document is not returned if there is only one match in the array?

This query will return the document, because there is a match on "type" : 6

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "usages.type": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And how is the query if there are 2 parameters like: usage.type should not be 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to describe your array like a nested field ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/nested.html

That may solve your issue.
See this example:

```
PUT /my_index 
{
}


PUT /my_index/_mapping/user
{
    "properties":
    {
        "usage":
        {
            "type": "nested"
        }
    }
}


PUT /my_index/user/1
{ 
    "usages": 
    [
        {
             "type": 1,
             "area": 207
        },
        {
            "type": 6,
            "area": 629
        }
    ]
}


GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "usages.type": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
          "match" {
            "usages.type": 1 AND 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used something similar to only include categories with certain ids in my results which is the the opposite of what you want to do (hence using "must_not" instead of "must" and "AND" instead of "OR" .

Comment: Same result ->  "must_not": [ { "match": { "usages.type": 1 } } (with or without AND) also return the document mentioned above.

Comment: have you replaced the full query (query/filtered/filter/bool/must_not/...) or just the part you have under must_not?

Comment: I've tried { "size": 10, "query": { "filtered": { "filter": { "bool": { "must_not": [ { "match": { "usages.type" : 1  }} ] } } } } } and a result was "usages": [ { "type": 1, "area": 4184 }, { "type": 20, "area": 2683 } ]

Answer (score 0):

Filtering using `must_not` on array will work by default. That is - when child objects are **NOT mapped** as `"type" : "nested"`.

Nested datatype is used only when you want to correlate values of multiple properties on child object (ex: type = 1 and area > 50) as described in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/nested.html).

@Artholl provided answer with the typo, so nested mapping never gets set properly. Here is working example:

```
PUT /my_index 


PUT /my_index/user/1
{ 
    "usages": 
    [
        {
             "type": 1,
             "area": 207
        },
        {
            "type": 6,
            "area": 629
        }
    ]
}


GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "usages.type": 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```